# Java Logical Test Questions Fancy Number

Tags: java, arrays

1. A fancy number is a number in the sequence 1, 1, 5, 17, 61, …

Note that first two fancy numbers are 1 and any fancy number other than the first two is sum of the three times previous one and two times the one before that. See below:

> 1, 1,
>
> 3*1 +2*1 = 5
>
> 3*5 +2*1 = 17
>
> 3*17 + 2*5 = 61

Write a function named isFancy that returns 1 if its integer argument is a Fancy number, otherwise it returns 0. The signature of the function is    int isFancy(int n)

Solutions:

```
public class fancynumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isFancy(5));
     System.out.println(isFancy(17));
      System.out.println(isFancy(61));
}

private static int isFancy(int i) {
    int previous = 1;
    int pprevious = 1;
    int set = 0;
    int currentvalue = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a<i;a++){

       currentvalue = 3*previous + 2*pprevious;

        if(currentvalue==i){
            set = 1;
            break;
        }
        else{
            set = 0;
        previous = currentvalue;
        pprevious = previous;
        }


    }
    return set;
}

}
```

what is the problem here? I couldn't fix this problem . Here, According to the condition , all functions should display 1 but only first displays 1 and other two's display 0. why?

Comment: This method will not return `true` for 1.

Answer (score 8):

You are overwriting the value of `previous` before you assign it to `pprevious`.

Change

```
    previous = currentvalue;
    pprevious = previous;
```

to

```
    pprevious = previous;
    previous = currentvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Test this; it works perfectly:

```
private static int isFancy(int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    int fancyNumber = 0;
    int pprevious = 1;
    int previous = 1;

    while (fancyNumber < n) {
        fancyNumber = ((3 * previous) + (2 * pprevious));
        pprevious = previous;
        previous = fancyNumber;
    }

    if (fancyNumber == n)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that you are not correctly updating the limits. You are always multiplying for the previous. For example, in the second execution you are doing `5*3 + 2*5`.

Answer (score -1):

oh, i find my mistakes . I replace it with original code, and get my answers

```
pprevious = previous;
previous = currentvalue;
```

Comment: You can accept Eran's Answer. You don't need to post the same solution again. :-)